# Error with Discovery service and discovery_registration.jar

Tags: web8, discovery-service

My Web 8 Content Deployer capability is not registered with the Discovery service (error from transport logs) and I'm trying to read the registered capabilities, but getting an error.  I'm using this command:

```
java -jar discovery-registration.jar read
```

Error:

```
2016-04-15 01:11:26,445 INFO  Main - Registration tool is run with following parameters:
2016-04-15 01:11:26,461 INFO  Main - Configuration file:     cd_storage_conf.xml
2016-04-15 01:11:26,461 INFO  Main - The Command is:         read
2016-04-15 01:11:26,461 INFO  RegistrationTool - Reading configuration from file: 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-04-15 01:11:26,601 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating OData client
2016-04-15 01:11:28,305 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Successfully created OData client
2016-04-15 01:11:28,320 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating token provider for OAuth enabled OData client
2016-04-15 01:11:28,508 INFO  DefaultDiscoveryClient - Capability: class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.TokenServiceCapability not found.
2016-04-15 01:11:28,508 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating token provider using TokenServiceUrl from configuration file

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: The TokenServiceUrl
is missing from ConfigurationRepository element
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.init(ODataClientProvider.java:61)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.<init>(ODataClientProvider.java:51)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.RegistrationTool.<init>(RegistrationTool.java:46)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.Main.main(Main.java:35)
Caused by: com.sdl.delivery.configuration.ConfigurationException: The TokenServiceUrl is missing from ConfigurationRepository elem
ent
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.createTokenProvider(ODataClientProvider.java:99)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.init(ODataClientProvider.java:58)
        ... 3 more
```

Discovery cd_storage conf:

```
  <ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc"
                      ConnectionTimeout="40000"
                      CacheEnabled="true"
                      CacheExpirationDuration="600"
                      ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10"
                      ClientId="registration"
                      ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=">
        <Roles>
            <Role Name="TokenServiceCapability" Url="http://localhost:8082/token.svc"/>

        </Roles>
    </ConfigRepository>
```

Comment: It looks like your token service capability is also not registered yet and you have Oauth enabled. So the tool firstly tries to get token from token service in order to read other capabilities, but can not get it...

Comment: where we can find this file discovery-registration.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check my Question (and answer) [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14460/error-on-web-8-1-1-cd-install-the-tokenservicecapability-is-not-configured-in-t)

The trick is to add TokenServiceUrl (TokenServiceUrl="http://10.177.4.83:8082/token.svc") as it somehow gets deleted when you do a quickinstall:

```
<ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://10.177.4.83:8082/discovery.svc"
                  ConnectionTimeout="40000"
                  CacheEnabled="true"
                  CacheExpirationDuration="600"
                  ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10"
                  ClientId="registration"
                  ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY="
                  TokenServiceUrl="http://10.177.4.83:8082/token.svc">
    <Roles>

        <Role Name="TokenServiceCapability" Url="http://10.177.4.83:8082/token.svc"/>
    </Roles>
</ConfigRepository>
```

Then run the discovery registration again.

Comment: Looks like 8.5's quickinstall still has the same defect :(

Comment: All of the shipped 8.5 `cd_storage_conf.xml` files include the TokenService Url properties. I've also confirmed that running `quickinstall.ps1` does not remove it.