# Error on Web 8.1.1 CD Install: The TokenServiceCapability is not configured in the Content Discovery Service http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc

Tags: web8, installation, discovery-service

I was getting the following error on Step 3:

```
The TokenServiceCapability is not configured in the Content Discovery Service http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc
```

Found that `TokenServiceUrl="http://localhost:8082/token.svc"` is missing from cd_storage_conf.xml from ConfigRepository node

Added and ran the discovery update

```
java -jar discovery-registration.jar update
```

And finally the command

```
Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id SampleCD -EnvironmentPurpose "Staging" -DiscoveryEndpointUrl http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc -AuthenticationType OAuth -ClientId registration -ClientSecret Reg1str@t10nP@ssw0rd
```

*Posting here to check if this is the right way

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4D16348C-7195-4E6B-8199-5DEC20D182C8&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dcdservices&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1461049503727&currentQuery=cdservices&currentScope=

Comment: This seems to be because of some issue in the quickinstall.ps1 script, as the original cd_storage file had the TokenServiceUrl element which somehow got replaced after the quickinstall..

Comment: Yes, realised it a couple of hours ago and answered him too. thanks.

Comment: Your other answer points back to this one. It's probably best to assume this one will get deleted, so it's a good idea to make sure all relevant details are in the other answer.