# Publishing fails on Transporting, SDL Web 8 ,DXA

Tags: publishing, dxa, web8, discovery-service

I installed SDL Web 8, and DXA 1.4 Java version in it.
I set up DXA by following documentation, and finally it's able to publish a page.
But publishing failed at Transporting phase.

Transporter output following error log.

```
2016-06-07 12:21:31,591 ERROR TransportService - Unable to establish transport to destination.
com.tridion.transport.TransportException: Unable to retrieve destination metadata
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:116) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerFactory.getDestinationController(DestinationControllerFactory.java:41) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.createOrLoadTransaction(TransactionProcessor.java:134) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.<init>(TransactionProcessor.java:48) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:252) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
Caused by: com.sdl.web.client.ClientException: Unable to obtain OAuth token from discovery service. Probably Discovery service is not up and running.
    at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.obtainTokenResult(DefaultOAuthClient.java:129) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
    at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.doFetchOAuthToken(DefaultOAuthClient.java:100) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
    at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.getToken(DefaultOAuthClient.java:79) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
    at com.sdl.web.client.impl.OAuthTokenProvider.getToken(OAuthTokenProvider.java:70) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.setHeaders(DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.java:209) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.java:214) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.java:125) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(TransportPoolConnector.java:80) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:54) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:36) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:108) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

It seems to be transporter failed to connect to Discovery Service.
I checked CD Environment by PowerShell.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-TtmCdEnvironment


EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
DiscoveryEndpointUrl : http://10.0.x.xx:8082/discovery.svc
Credentials          : "AuthenticationType":"OAuth", "ClientId":"registration", "ClientSecret":"********"
IsOffline            : False
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {DxaSiteType, DxaExampleSite}
Id                   : CdEnvironment2
ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

And I request Discovery Endpoint URL 'http://10.0.x.xx:8082/discovery.svc' on browser, following string appears. I think this means the Discovery Service is running.

```
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
```

And cd_storage_conf.xml's ConfigRepository of the Discovery Service is following. I added 'TokenServiceUrl' attribute according to this post:
[Error with Discovery service and discovery_registration.jar](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14428/error-with-discovery-service-and-discovery-registration-jar)
Also 'ClientId' and 'ClientSecret' are same as CD Environment.

```
    <ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://10.0.1.98:8082/discovery.svc"
                      ConnectionTimeout="40000"
                      CacheEnabled="true"
                      CacheExpirationDuration="600"
                      ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10"
                      ClientId="registration"
                      ClientSecret="password"
TokenServiceUrl="http://10.0.1.98:8082/token.svc"
>
        <Roles>
            <Role Name="TokenServiceCapability" Url="http://10.0.1.98:8082/token.svc"/>
            <Role Name="DeployerCapability" Url="http://10.0.1.98:8084/httpupload">
                <Property Name="undo.enabled" Value="false"/>
                <Property Name="encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
            </Role>
        </Roles>
    </ConfigRepository>
```

Why does publishing fail?

Is something missing in configuration?

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Which ClientId and ClientSecret are you using in your OAuth credentials. The user `registration` has no permissions to publish content to the Content Deployer. If you are using the default users and their roles you need to use this user `cmuser` where the default password is `CMUserP@ssw0rd`. Please make sure you update these passwords.

You can find the default users and their passwords in the `cd_ambient_conf.xml` from your discovery service (config folder)

Comment: There were two different promblems. One is that I didn't install hotfix CD_8.1.1.1957, so Discovery Service wasn't installed properly.
Another one is TtmCdEnvironmet's ClientId have to be 'cmuser' as mentioned.