# Discovery Service 'discovery-registration' command fails by Unable to obtain OAuth token

Tags: web8, installation, discovery-service

I installed Content Delivery services  by following quickinstall.sh command.
Enviroment is Linux and Java.

```
./quickinstall.sh --all -s /home/user/Content\ Delivery/roles --license /home/user/cd_licenses.xml
```

Then modifed Discovery Service's cd_storage_conf.xml, added 'TokenServiceUrl' attribute according to this post.
[Error with Discovery service and discovery_registration.jar](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14428/error-with-discovery-service-and-discovery-registration-jar)

Also I modified storage setting to my DB setting.

```
<ConfigRepository ServiceUri="http://10.0.x.xx:8082/discovery.svc"
                  ConnectionTimeout="40000"
                  CacheEnabled="true"
                  CacheExpirationDuration="600"
                  ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10"
                  ClientId="registration"
                  ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY="
                  TokenServiceUrl="http://10.0.x.xx:8082/token.svc">
    <Roles>
        <Role Name="TokenServiceCapability" Url="http://10.0.x.x:8082/token.svc"/>
    </Roles>
</ConfigRepository>
```

But error occured when doing following command. I put 'discovery-registration.jar' in Discovery Service's config directory

java -jar discovery-registration.jar update

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-98 config]# java -jar discovery-registration.jar update
2016-06-08 05:20:18,412 INFO  Main - Registration tool is run with following parameters:
2016-06-08 05:20:18,415 INFO  Main - Configuration file:         cd_storage_conf.xml
2016-06-08 05:20:18,416 INFO  Main - The Command is:             update
2016-06-08 05:20:18,417 INFO  RegistrationTool - Reading configuration from file: 'cd_storage_conf.xml'
2016-06-08 05:20:18,494 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating OData client
2016-06-08 05:20:19,388 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Successfully created OData client
2016-06-08 05:20:19,388 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating token provider for OAuth enabled OData client
2016-06-08 05:20:19,774 INFO  DefaultDiscoveryClient - Capability: class com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.TokenServiceCapability not found.
2016-06-08 05:20:19,776 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Creating token provider using TokenServiceUrl from configuration file
2016-06-08 05:20:19,869 INFO  ODataClientProvider - Successfully created token provider for OAuth enabled OData client
2016-06-08 05:20:19,869 INFO  UpdateCommand - Updating Capabilities in the discovery-service...
Exception in thread "main" com.sdl.web.client.ClientException: Unable to obtain OAuth token from discovery service. Probably Discovery service is not up and running.
        at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.obtainTokenResult(DefaultOAuthClient.java:129)
        at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.doFetchOAuthToken(DefaultOAuthClient.java:100)
        at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.getToken(DefaultOAuthClient.java:79)
        at com.sdl.web.client.impl.OAuthTokenProvider.getToken(OAuthTokenProvider.java:70)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.ODataClientProvider.provideClient(ODataClientProvider.java:129)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.command.AbstractCommand.getCapabilitiesFromService(AbstractCommand.java:33)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.command.AbstractCommand.lambda$getExistingCapabilities$2(AbstractCommand.java:65)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.command.AbstractCommand.getExistingCapabilities(AbstractCommand.java:67)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.command.UpdateCommand.performCommand(UpdateCommand.java:46)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.RegistrationTool.performCommand(RegistrationTool.java:62)
        at com.sdl.web.discovery.registration.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientException: Unable to process response from OData service.
        at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:224)
        at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.sendRequest(BasicEndpointCaller.java:145)
        at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.doPostEntity(BasicEndpointCaller.java:105)
        at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.obtainTokenResult(DefaultOAuthClient.java:115)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:204)
        ... 20 more
```

'discovery.svc' and 'token.svc' url returns following each result.
I think this means Discovery Service is runnning normally.

http://10.0.x.xx:8082/discovery.svc

```
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
```

http://10.0.x.xx:8082/token.svc

```
SDL Web OAuth 2.0 Token Servlet.
```

Why does 'discovery-registration.jar' command fail?

Is there any required configuration?

Regards,

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but did you restart the discovery service after changing the configuration?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, if CliendId written in cd_storage_conf.xml is wrong, this command returns {"error":"Access Denied: Incorrect credentials."} quickly, so the service seems working. Only when CliendId and ClientSecret are correct, this error occurs after 30 seconds.

Comment: which version of CD are you using ? And is this issue in unix platform ?

Comment: I'm using SDL Web 8.1.1, OS is Linux and Java is 1.8.0_91.

Comment: There was an issue due to SecureRandom in unix platforms which caused timeouts when generating OAuth token. This was fixed in an hotfix. Are you using latest 8.1.1 hotfix ?

Comment: The problem was fixed by applying hotfix CD_8.1.1.1957! But I coudn't find it on Tridion World Web site at this time. I got it from SDL FTP site.

Comment: thanks for confirming, added the same as answer to be useful if faced by others.

Comment: Yet another quite crucial basic functionality that isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue in a Windows environment with SDL Web 8.1.1. What got me past the error was removing these two attributes from the ConfigRepository element in the cd_storage_conf.xml I used to run the discovery update:

**ClientId="registration"
ClientSecret="encrypted:xXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxX"**

Since I am not using OAuth, I guess having those attributes in the conf tricked the update into thinking it needed to retrieve an OAuth token, which caused issues since OAuth is not enabled.

Answer (score 4):

There was an issue due to SecureRandom in unix platforms which caused timeouts when generating OAuth token. This was fixed as a hotfix and available in latest 8.1.1 hotfix release. Applying hotfix should fix this issue.

Comment: which patch did you applied, can you tell me the name_version?

Comment: Hirokazu Shikata mentioned in his comment that after using  CD_8.1.1.1957 it is fixed.