# Problem in CMS publishing SDL Web 8.1: Unable to establish transport to destination

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

We are facing issue with publishing page from CMS to CDA with Discovery Service installed on Linux server.

CMS Error logs:

> Transport service failed to transport. Unable to establish transport to
>   destination.Unable to retrieve destination
>   metadata

We have installed  one CMS Server and 2 discovery services as below:

- First  for “staging” target on windows server, here  publishing is  working fine.
- Second  for “Live” target on Linux server. Here discovery service URL  is working fine (OAuth=”False”) and also accessible from CMS Server, but when we Publish any content from CMS to “Live” target bound with this service, It throws the above error.

Please find attached transport service log file taken from CMS Server, also there is no log found on CDA Linux server for this issue.

We have checked all the posts on Stack Overflow related to this issue but not found any solution yet.
Please help us to resolve this issue.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

> Transport config error Logs:
>   2016-07-11 19:11:51,934 DEBUG TransportService - Starting handing of a transaction
>   2016-07-11 19:11:51,981 INFO  TransactionProcessor - No existing transport transaction information for: tcm:0-69-66560 creating new transaction state
>   2016-07-11 19:11:51,996 DEBUG TransactionHeader - Writing[TransactionHeader transactionId=tcm:0-69-66560 control=COMMIT] to C:\Temp\tcm_0-69-66560.Content\transaction.xml
>   2016-07-11 19:11:52,465 INFO  DestinationControllerMonitor - Starting DestinationControllerMonitor.
>   2016-07-11 19:11:52,465 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Creating new destination controller.
>   2016-07-11 19:11:52,465 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - DestinationControllerMonitor started.
>   2016-07-11 19:11:52,481 DEBUG DestinationController - Created Destination controller with maximum polling attempts: 900 and timeout (ms.) of: 900000
>   2016-07-11 19:11:52,481 DEBUG DestinationController - Interval between polls is: 5000 ms.
>   2016-07-11 19:11:52,481 DEBUG DestinationController - Maximum sending threads for destination: 5
>   2016-07-11 19:11:52,497 INFO  TransportPoolManager - Creating a new TransportPoolConnector, because no available connectors in connection pool
>   2016-07-11 19:11:52,512 DEBUG TransportPoolConnector - Configuring TransportPoolConnector.
>   2016-07-11 19:12:24,559 ERROR TransportService - Unable to establish transport to destination.
>   com.tridion.transport.TransportException: Unable to retrieve destination metadata
>       at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.(DestinationController.java:116) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerFactory.getDestinationController(DestinationControllerFactory.java:41) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.createOrLoadTransaction(TransactionProcessor.java:134) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.(TransactionProcessor.java:48) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:252) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>   Caused by: com.sdl.web.client.ClientException: Unable to obtain OAuth token from discovery service. Probably Discovery service is not up and running.
>       at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.obtainTokenResult(DefaultOAuthClient.java:129) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
>       at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.doFetchOAuthToken(DefaultOAuthClient.java:100) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
>       at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.getToken(DefaultOAuthClient.java:79) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
>       at com.sdl.web.client.impl.OAuthTokenProvider.getToken(OAuthTokenProvider.java:70) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
>       at com.sdl.web.client.impl.SecuredCapabilityProvider.getCapability(SecuredCapabilityProvider.java:37) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
>       at com.sdl.web.client.CapabilityProvider.getCapability(CapabilityProvider.java:20) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
>       at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.configure(DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector.java:73) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.configure(TransportPoolConnector.java:50) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.connection.pooling.TransportPoolManager.createTransporterInstance(TransportPoolManager.java:235) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.connection.pooling.TransportPoolManager.getTransporterConnector(TransportPoolManager.java:174) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:32) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.(DestinationController.java:108) ~[cd_transport.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       ... 4 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientException: Unable to process response from OData service.
>       at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:224) ~[odata_client.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>       at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.sendRequest(BasicEndpointCaller.java:145) ~[odata_client.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>       at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.doPostEntity(BasicEndpointCaller.java:105) ~[odata_client.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>       at com.sdl.web.client.impl.DefaultOAuthClient.obtainTokenResult(DefaultOAuthClient.java:115) ~[discovery-client-lightweight.jar:8.1.1-1009]
>       ... 15 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
>       at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:204) ~[odata_client.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>       ... 18 common frames omitted

Comment: did you check http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14833/discovery-service-discovery-registration-command-fails-by-unable-to-obtain-oau